# What does it mean for a class to inherit from an object which is not a type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, metaclass

I encoutered a weird case of class inheritance in Python 3.8.

I can create a class by inheriting from an instance which is not itself a `type`. I expected a `TypeError` in that case, but that is not what happens.

```
class B:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls)

b = B()  # prints: () {}

class A(b):  # I expected a TypeError here
    x = "foo"
# prints: ('A', (<__main__.B object at 0x7f32bd102390>,),
#         {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'A', 'x': 'foo'}) {}

print(A)  # <__main__.B object at 0x7f20556c93d0>
print(isinstance(A, B))  # True
print(isinstance(A, type))  # False
```

It looks like when I give `B()` as base for `A`, then `B` is being used as the metaclass.

Is my understanding correct? Why is that the case? And I cannot seem to find anything regarding this behaviour, is it documented or is it an implementation quirk specific to cPython?

Comment: It seems like calling `A()` at the end of your code snippet raises `TypeError: 'B' object is not callable`

Comment: @JakeLevi Yes, this is because A ends up being an instance of B instead of a type... for some semantics reason I cannot see.

Comment: Also, if I comment out your definition of `B` and replace it with `class B: pass`, then the line `class A(b):` raises `TypeError: B() takes no arguments`, as you expected. Therefore I'm guessing the answer to your question is related to the behaviour of the `__new__` special method, which you can read more about here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the type constructor will check the bases to guess the most derived metaclass. It will then see the instance of `A`, and use its class as the "most derived metaclass". So, yes, the class of things that  go in "bases" is used as the metaclass.

From that point, it will call the retrieved "metaclass"  to build the B class itself. As it is a class, it is called, this triggers the class' `__new__` as usual. Since it returns an instance of "A" that is what you get as  being your "B": Python does not get in the way to verify if whatever the metaclass callable returned is itself a "class" - it can be any object. This gives one the flexibility to abuse the class statement to build other kind of objects, given appropriate super-classes or metaclasses. In this case, it just happened to not raise a TypeError and return you an instance of "A". (but you had to adjust the class' `__new__` to avoid the TypeError)

```
In [16]: class A: 
    ...:     def __new__(cls, *args, **kw): 
    ...:         print(args, kw) 
    ...:         return  super().__new__(cls) 
    ...:          
    ...:                

In [17]: class B(A()): pass                     
() {}
('B', (<__main__.A object at 0x7f26862395b0>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'B'}) {}

In [18]: type(B)        
Out[18]: __main__.A

In [19]: isinstance(B, A)                       
Out[19]: True
```

Comment: Thanks. The keyword here really is "derived metaclass". From there I could find all the documentation I needed.